# Pandas: Update in a column for different rows based on the values present in the same row for a different column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I have an excel named Trial.xlsx.  In this there is a column prod_code with 900+ data. Now using pandas I want to insert a new column named sub_category and based on the string present in prod_code, a different string need to be updated in sub_category column. Finally this data is to be written in a different excel sheet

I tried to use np.select and gave different conditions. But using this method, only the last condition is satisfied. So in column sub_category only a certain condition has data and remaining are filled with 0. Please help in resolving the issue in my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

database = pd.read_excel("Trial.xlsx")
database_df = pd.DataFrame(database)
database_df['sub-category'] = ""

conditions_vehicle = [
    database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_CAR',
    (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_CYCLE') | (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_ONTRACK_ACTIVA6G'),
    (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_ELECTRIC_BIKE') | (database_df['prod_code']== 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_ATHER')]
choices_vehicle = ['4W','2W','EV-2W']
database_df['sub-category'] = np.select(conditions_vehicle, choices_vehicle)

conditions_jewellery = [
    (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_BLUESTONE_DIAMOND') | (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_BLUESTONE_GOLD'),
    database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_JEWELLERY',
    database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_KALYANJEWELLERY_QC',
    database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_PCJDIAMOND_QC',
    (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_AKSHAYA_TRITYIYA_2021') | (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_ANNIVERSARY_JEWELLERY') | (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_WEDDING_JEWELLERY'),
    (database_df['prod_code'] == 'CLASSIC_TAGGED_TANISHQ_QC')]
choices_jewellery = ['Blue stone jewellers', 'General Jewellery', 'Kalyan jewellers', 'PCJ jewellers', 'Special Occasion', 'Tanishq jewellers']
database_df['sub-category'] = np.select(conditions_jewellery, choices_jewellery)
database_df.to_excel("Final_data.xlsx", sheet_name='Test_data',index=False)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of prod_code column and desired sub-category column?

it looks like in sub-category column, you only need remove word 'classic' from prod_code column. is it correct?

Comment: no @kevinwu. My expectation is if in prod_code[0] = CLASSIC_CYCLE, I want sub_category[0] = 2W. Basically, I want to update the column sub_category based on string present in column prod_code

Comment: How about you create dict of cheatsheet? and then use apply lambda to navigate them?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
cheatsheet = {
  'CLASSIC_CYCLE':'2W', 
  'CLASSIC_CAR':'4W', 
  'CLASSIC_TAGGED_BLUESTONE_DIAMOND':'Blue stone jewellers'}

database_df['prod_code'].apply(lambda x : cheatsheet[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code work...

```
import pandas as pd
database = pd.read_excel("Trial.xlsx")
database_df = pd.DataFrame(database)

def update_sub_category(row):
    # Category : Vehicle
    if row['prod_code'] == "CLASSIC_CAR":
        return "4W"
    elif row['prod_code'] in ["CLASSIC_CYCLE", "CLASSIC_TAGGED_ONTRACK_ACTIVA6G"]:
        return "2W"
    elif row['prod_code'] in ["CLASSIC_ELECTRIC_BIKE", "CLASSIC_TAGGED_ATHER"]:
        return "EV-2W"

    # Category: Jewellery
    elif row['prod_code'] in ["CLASSIC_TAGGED_BLUESTONE_DIAMOND", "CLASSIC_TAGGED_BLUESTONE_GOLD"]:
        return "Blue Stone Jewellers"
    elif row['prod_code'] == "CLASSIC_JEWELLERY":
        return "General Jewellery"
    elif row['prod_code'] == "CLASSIC_TAGGED_KALYANJEWELLERY_QC":
        return "Kalyan Jewellers"
    elif row['prod_code'] == "CLASSIC_TAGGED_PCJDIAMOND_QC":
        return "PCJ Jewellers"
    elif row['prod_code'] == "CLASSIC_TAGGED_TANISHQ_QC":
        return "Tanishq Jewellers"
    elif row['prod_code'] in ["CLASSIC_AKSHAYA_TRITYIYA_2021", "CLASSIC_ANNIVERSARY_JEWELLERY", "CLASSIC_WEDDING_JEWELLERY"]:
        return "Special Occasion"
database_df['sub_category'] = database_df.apply(update_sub_category, axis=1)
database_df['sub_category'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
database_df.to_excel("Final_data.xlsx", sheet_name='Test_data',index=False)
```